# Do you know any projects where ZeroMQ was used? Both success and failure stories are valuable

Tags: zeromq, use-case

I'm interested in using ZeroMQ in a project, but I'd like to hear about other's experience with it. I did some searching but found only mongrel2 project. Have you heard about other projects where it is used? What companies use ZeroMQ in production?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for stories, not a programming question.

Answer (score 15):

We replaced usage of Unix named pipes with ZeroMQ. The communication overhead is equally not noticeable. And we got additional benefits:

- No limit on the message size.
- Ability to send the messages to remote boxes.
- No need to write our own thread for non-blocking send.
- Ability to receive messages from multiple sources.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Could you provide a bit more numerical data? Is throughput or latency important in your system? Have you done any benchmarks? What languages are you gluing with 0mq?

Comment: Throughput is more important for us. I measured the performance before and after the migration. ZMQ over TCP or IPC kept the applications equally fast. Numerical data depend on CPU (100,000 msg/s). We use Python.

Answer (score 4):

The webserver [Mongrel2](http://mongrel2.org/) uses ZeroMQ for its messaging kernel.

Comment: Yes, I know that fact. Though it would be awesome if Zed Shaw described his experience using ZeroMQ when developing mongrel2

Answer (score 2):

ZeroRPC is a production ready offering based on ZeroMQ. Here's the source of my info., complete list of 0mq based projects: http://www.zeromq.org/docs:labs